# Windows to Linux port c++ errors

Tags: c++, linux, templates, gcc, typedef

I am working on porting a large c++ application from Windows to Linux and so far I've been working through the issues and replacing the Windows specific stuff with standards code.

I've come across a template that begins like this

```
#define IC __attribute__((inline))

template <typename object_type, typename base_type = intrusive_base>
class intrusive_ptr
{
private:
    typedef base_type base_type;
    typedef object_type object_type;
    typedef intrusive_ptr<object_type, base_type> self_type;
    typedef const object_type* (intrusive_ptr::*unspecified_bool_type) () const;

...

public:
    IC intrusive_ptr();
    IC intrusive_ptr(object_type* rhs);
    IC intrusive_ptr(self_type const& rhs);
    IC ~intrusive_ptr();
    IC self_type& operator= (object_type* rhs);
    IC self_type& operator= (self_type const& rhs);
    IC object_type& operator*() const; // original
    IC object_type* operator->() const;   // original

... 
};


#define TEMPLATE_SPECIALIZATION template <typename object_type, typename base_type>
#define _intrusive_ptr intrusive_ptr<object_type, base_type>

TEMPLATE_SPECIALIZATION
IC typename _intrusive_ptr::object_type& _intrusive_ptr::operator* () const
{
    VERIFY(m_object);
    return (*m_object);
}

TEMPLATE_SPECIALIZATION
IC typename _intrusive_ptr::object_type* _intrusive_ptr::operator->() const
{
    VERIFY(m_object);
    return (m_object);
}
```

I am having trouble understanding a couple of things.

What is the reason for the

```
typedef base_type base_type;
```

GCC has issues with it as it "shadows template parm ‘class base_type’". Obviously there was some purpose for it and the Microsoft compiler must have allowed it.

I also have issues with the TEMPLATE_SPECIALIZATION stuff below giving errors like

```
error: prototype for ‘typename intrusive_ptr<object_type, base_type>::object_type& intrusive_ptr<object_type, base_type>::operator*() const’ does not match any in class ‘intrusive_ptr<object_type, base_type>’
```

&

```
error: candidate is: object_type& intrusive_ptr<object_type, base_type>::operator*() const
```

I am not the most proficient with c++ as it isn't my primary language but I have learned a lot so far by attempting this port and will continue to learn a lot. I'm a bit stuck on these errors at the moment and hope someone might be able to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `typedef` for `base_type` is quite simple: to make the type used in the template argument list available to users of `intrusive_ptr` (although, since the type is actually 'private' it doesn't really much sense), the type is defined with in the template definition. The trivial fix is to change the code to become

```
template <typename Object_type, typename Base_type = intrusive_base>
class intrusive_ptr
{
private:
    typedef Base_type base_type;
    typedef Object_type object_type;
    // ...
```

I'd think that also fixes the problem with the overload: it seems the problem with not finding the correct overload is a follow-up problem of the nested type not being defined.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would come down to something simple. I appreciate the help.